# Add an extra condition for login in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to authenticate a user with the obvious email and password and also if the ban_status is set to 0 in the database.

I have had a look at the newest laravel docs and I have tried it this way in the AuthenticateUsers.php

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required', 'ban_status' => '0',
    ]);
}
```

This does not do anything as far as I can tell and will log in the user regardless whether there ban status is 0 or not, where should I be doing this extra condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a long story short, what you are actually trying to do in the code you posted is to check the `ban_status` value being passed in from the `$request`, or in other words the login form.

My understanding of your questions is that this is not really what you want.

Instead, try this:

Override the `login` method of `AuthenticatesUsers` by defining it in `LoginController`, with the following small addition to check for your `ban_status`:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        if ($this->guard()->user()->ban_status === 0) { // ADDED THIS CHECK
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if (! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: How would I override this? Would I make a route for the post request for /login to go to the LoginController@login ?

Comment: Actually, all you would need to do is copy and paste the new code to your LoginController. Everything else can stay the same. What we are doing is "overriding" the login method of the AuthenticatesUsers trait. If you are unfamiliar with this concept check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) and then [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: Ah yes it worked, my issue was I was using the wrong Request, where would I define where a user go if the login fails? i.e there ban_status is not 0

Comment: Any failure? Or specifically if the user was banned?

Comment: Well I have done this, https://i.gyazo.com/de10308defbf7ace506fe34b041bb537.png  how does that look to you, is that secure?

Comment: Actually I'm having second thoughts about redirecting them to a banned page as anyone could access this, what would you suggest? returning an error on the form or protecting the /banned route somehow to only allow people redirected from this check to access it?

Comment: Done :) Thank you for the help

Comment: there are other places were login can happen, for instance [after reseting the password](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L113). What's needed is to implement a new [user provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)

Answer (score 3):

To build on tam's answer, I added a redirect based on the failed "banned" status because otherwise I would still get logged in, even though the condition was false. Here's the override of the login function that worked for me, placed in LoginController.php :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{       
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) 
    {           
        if ($this->guard()->user()->ban_status === 0) { // ADDED THIS CHECK
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        } else { // logout and redirect if failed
            $this->guard()->logout();
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    $this->username() => 'You have been banned',
                ]);         
        }
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually authenticate the users:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $password=$request->get('password');
    $email=$request->get('email');
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password,'ban_status'=>0]) )
    {     
        return redirect()->intended('/');   
    }
    else 
    {
        return redirect('/login');      
    }       
}
```

Comment: you lose throttling if you do it this way

Answer (score 1):

Rather than override the `login()` function, as in the accepted answer, it is probably better to override the `credentials()` function. This function is expected to return an array of values to check for in the database.

When comparing against a fixed value as in the original question, just make an array and merge it in:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(
        $request->only($this->username(), "password"),
        ["ban_status" => 0]
    );
}
```

Or, to compare against a dynamic value (e.g. there is an `<input type="hidden" name="your_field" value="42"/>` in the login form) then you can simply add it to the list of returned request fields.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), "password", "your_field");
}
```

Why is this better? The user is never authenticated at all in the system – the database query will not return a result unless all conditions match. In the accepted answer, the user initially passes the login attempt. As user3703567 [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40253839/1255289), this can cause issues.